# Third degree parabola, a tangent and a line parallel to the tangent

Tags: functions

a 3rd degree parabola touches the x axis at zero point. The tangent at point P(-3|0) is parallel to the line y=6x. What is the function of the parabola?

Please help i‘m having difficulties solving this question

Comment: The question is confusing in the absence of a definition of what's the meaning of "3rd degree parabola". Also, does "touches the x axis at zero point" means that the graph is tangent to the horizontal axis at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Do you mean a third degree *polynomial*, also called a cubic function? If so, start by noticing that $x=0$ and $x=-3$ are roots of the cubic. If the other root is $a$, then you can use the product rule of differentiation to find $a$.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of clarifications to the question, I assume that a "3rd degree parabola" means that your function is $$y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
I will also use $$y'=3ax^2+2bx+c$$
I also assume that  "touches the x axis at zero point" means that the graph is tangent to the horizontal axis at $(0,0)$. Then you have for equations:

1. $(0,0)$ is on the curve $$0=a0^3+b0^2+c0+d$$or $d=0$.
2. The curve is tangent to the $x$ axis at $0$, so $y'(0)=0$ $$0=3a0^2+2b0+c$$ or $c=0$.
3. The point $(-3,0)$ is on the curve $$0=a(-3)^2+b(-3)^2$$ You can rewrite this as $b=3a$.
4. The tangent to the curve at $x=-3$ has the slope $y'(-3)$ which is the same slope as the line $y=6x$, so $$y'(-3)=6$$
   Plugging in the value for $x$ and $b$, you get
   $$6=3a(-3)^2+2(3a)(-3)=9a$$

From here $a=\frac 23$, $b=2$ and $c=d=0$.

**Note** that if "touching" means that it just goes through the point, without the condition on the slope, then you don't have enough equations to solve the problem.